# zookeeper start using daemon on windows 10

Tags: background, apache-zookeeper, daemon

I am trying to start zookeeper on windows 10 in the background using -daemon command and it comes back with "ERROR Invalid arguments, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-daemon"

Error. here is the command i used

zookeeper-server-start.bat -daemon config/zookeeper.properties

If I remove -daemon I can start the service with no issues. This runs in the foreground and i have to keep zookeeper window open (which is annoying). I want to start the zookeeper in the background on windows 10 using -daemon. Anyone tried this? Thank you.